# verificar matriz simétrica

Tags: python, matriz

O exercício pede para fazer uma função que verificasse se uma matriz é simétrica.

Linhas e colunas são, respectivamente, as variáveis `i` e `j` o programa retorna sempre true, porém nao sei o que há de errado.

```
def simetrica(mat):
    for i in range(len(mat)):
        for j in range(len(mat[0])):
            if mat[i][j]!=mat[j][i]:
                return False
    return True
ela=[[3,2,5],[2,5,6,],[5,6,7]]
fazer=simetrica(ela)
```

Comment: Parece estar correto. Conseguiria fazer uma otimização, de percorrer apenas metade da matriz, pois fazer a comparação `i, j = A, B` será a mesma comparação de `i, j = B, A`, sendo `A` e `B` posições na matriz, então não há necessidade de fazer as duas; uma delas já é suficiente para garantir a simetria.

Answer (score 1):

> "*o programa retorna sempre true*"

Não é verdade, eu testei com uma matriz não-simétrica e ele retornou `False`:

```
m = [ [3, 2, 5], [1, 5, 6], [15, 4, 7] ]
print(simetrica(m)) # False
```

Só tem alguns detalhes para acertar/melhorar.

Na verdade o que você tem não é bem uma matriz, e sim uma lista de listas (a única forma nativa da linguagem de simular matrizes).

Isso porque em uma matriz de dimensões M x N (M linhas e N colunas), todas as M linhas possuem exatamente N elementos. Mas em uma lista de listas, não há essa obrigação (não há nada na linguagem que obrigue a ter um tamanho determinado, é você que tem que controlar e garantir isso): cada "linha" pode ter uma quantidade diferente de elementos. Então nada impede que eu tenha uma "matriz-que-não-é-uma-matriz":

```
m = [
  [3],
  [2, 5, 6],
  [5, 6]
]
```

Sendo assim, a função também precisaria verificar se todas as "linhas" possuem a mesma quantidade de elementos. Por exemplo, se passarmos uma lista como:

```
m = [
  [3, 2, 5],
  [2, 5, 6, 8],
  [5, 6, 7]
]
```

A função retorna `True`. Isso porque o *loop* interno (`for j`) só vai até `len(mat[0])`, que é o tamanho da primeira "linha", e como ela só tem 3 elementos, o quarto elemento da segunda "linha" (o número 8) é ignorado pelo *loop*.

Além disso, como uma [matriz simétrica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix) só pode ser quadrada (a quantidade de linhas é igual à quantidade de colunas), podemos usar [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) para verificar se cada uma das "linhas" tem o mesmo tamanho da "matriz". Algo assim:

```
if any(len(linha) != len(mat) for linha in mat):
    return False
```

Ou seja, se alguma "linha" tem um tamanho diferente, eu retorno `False` e nem preciso prosseguir.

Outra melhoria é que você não precisa percorrer todos os elementos. Verificar a diagonal é redundante (pois na diagonal, `i` é igual a `j`, então na verdade você estará comparando o elemento com ele mesmo). Basta ir até a diagonal e comparar uma das "metades" com a outra "metade". Por exemplo, se eu comparei o elemento `mat[0][1]` com `mat[1][0]`, é redundante fazer outra comparação de `mat[1][0]` com `mat[0][1]`. Ou seja, o `j` não precisa ir do início ao fim, ele pode ir somente até `i`:

```
def simetrica(mat):
    if any(len(linha) != len(mat) for linha in mat):
        return False

    for i in range(len(mat)):
        for j in range(i): # só vou até a diagonal
            if mat[i][j] != mat[j][i]:
                return False
    return True
```

---

Um detalhe é que assim temos que percorrer a matriz duas vezes: uma para verificar os tamanhos (o `if any(...)`), e outra para comparar os elementos. Mas se quiser, pode fazer tudo de uma vez:

```
def simetrica(mat):
    for i, linha in enumerate(mat):
        if len(linha) != len(mat): # tamanho diferente, não é matriz quadrada
            return False # então não pode ser simétrica
        for j in range(i):
            if linha[j] != mat[j][i]:
                return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Vamos la. Uma matriz é simétrica quando a ela é igual sua transposta. e para isso ser verdade ela necessariamente tem que ser quadrada. em outras palavras Aij == Aji para qualquer elemento dessa matriz.

O código abaixo demonstra isso:

```
M1 = [[3,5,6],
     [5,2,4],
     [6,4,8]]

M2 = [[3,5,6],
     [5,2,4],
     [6,7,8]]

def ver_simetri(M):
    for i in range(len(M)):
        for j  in range(len(M[0])):
            if M[i][j] != M[j][i]:
                return False
    return True
```

Se aplicar a função em M1 irá retorna True enquanto que em M2 ira retorna False. Basta que Aij seja diferente de Aji uma unica vez para a matriz não ser simétrica.
Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Esse não é exatamente o mesmo código da pergunta? Não entendi muito bem o que quis colocar com a resposta.

Comment: Me desculpe. não tinha reparado no código. Só quis esclarecer o procedimento.

Comment: Se quiser posso remover a resposta.

Comment: Isso só depende de você... só comentei porque realmente não havia entendido sua intenção.

Comment: Acho que pode ajudar pessoas que tenha essa duvida.